# OpenGL: push/pop matrix VS translate forth and back

Tags: java, c, opengl

I'd like to know what is faster (pseudocode):

```
glPushMatrix()
glTranslate2f(x, y)
// do drawing
glPopMatrix()
```

or

```
glTranslate2f(x, y)
// do drawing
glTranslate2f(-x, -y)
```

The drawing part is not expected to translate nor move, it's just drawing vertices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A short test of runtime has determined. The first :P

Comment: Oh, that's quite surprising. Any idea why is that?

Comment: I'm really not sure. I just know that after every program compiled I get a runtime conclusion and the first one topped the last.

Comment: @MightyPork: push/pop just has to set a single pointer (one operation) and in case of the push make a copy (16 operations). glTranslate has to make build a translation matrix (12 operations setting elements to 0, 3 operations to set the translation vector, 1 operation to set the ww-element), make a full 4×4 matrix-matrix multiplication (64 multiplications, 12 additions) and a full copy onto the stack (16 operations) = a total of 96 operations. pop(=1) < push(=16+1=17) << translate(=96).

Comment: Thanks for expansion @datenwolf, that makes sense. Any idea if it's this fast for all push/pop operations (attrib etc)?